# In the sample,why float convert to int print different result?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float x = 3.8, y = 5.2;
    int a, b, c;
    float d = x + y;
    a = d;
    b = (int)(x + y);
    c = (int)(3.8 + 5.2);
    printf("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

> ```
> 9,8,9
> ```

And I thought `9,9,9` is the right output, please tell me, why.

Comment: For me it's `9,9,9` https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uk8QhbAymYacOIvs

Comment: In `3.8 + 5.2` you are adding two `double` values. In `x + y` you are adding two `float` values. Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Found the cause.When I remove gcc flag -std=c11,it print 9,9,9.When I add -std=c11,it print 9,8,9.

Comment: Reopened. This is not the normal floating point inaccurate question. There are a variety of reasons behind the output that I feel the duplicate does not cover.

Answer (score 5):

In a single precision IEEE754 (the `float` scheme most likely used on your platform), `x` is `3.7999999523162841796875` and `y` is `5.19999980926513671875`. The sum of those is a little under 9, and the cast to `int` truncates the result. (Note that `float x = 3.8` actually truncates the `double` constant `3.8` to a `float`: `3.8f` is a constant of type `float`.)

But `3.8 + 5.2` is computed in *double* precision. In double precision IEEE754 `3.8` is `3.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875` and `5.2` is `5.20000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125`. This sums to just over 9, and so the `int` truncation recovers 9.

The fact that `a` and `b` are different is due to floating point evaluations not being *strict* on your compiler. You should be able to change its settings should you need to.

Comment: But can you explain why that happens for `b`, but not for `a`? I believe that's what the question is actually about.

Comment: @Angew: Not strict FP is the only explanation for that (as I'm sure you know - you're being nice and asking me to spruce up the answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.@Angew I hava the same puzzle.

Comment: The program produces `9,9,9` on OS/X with clang with or without optimisations. Another case of non strict FP?